# RN + Cocoapods = library not found for -lPods-XXX

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile, cocoapods

I feel this question have been asked again and again but I swear I tested every solution seen on the internet and it's still happening.

Basically I moved my React Native project to using cocoapods. See my Podfile below. When I pod install I get added "libPods-XXX.a" to my "Link Binary With Librairies" build phase. I guess that's how Cocoapods works?

But when libPods-XXX.a is there I can't build, always get the error "library not found for -lPods-XXX". If I remove it manually it works fine. But then next pod install will add it.

What I tried already :

- I am using worskspace file
- "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to Yes in Debug, no in my other Schemes, for the XXX project and for every pods installed.
- "Other linker flags" in my target is set to "$(inherited)"
- "Library search path" in my target is set to "$(inherited)"
- Already tried to deintegrate and resinstall multiple times, same goes for node modules

I am really running out of ideas here. Can anyone point me to something else I might be missing?

Thanks

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target :XXX do
    pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
    pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
    pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
    pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
    pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
    pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
    pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
    pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
    pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
    pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
    pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
    pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
    pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
    pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
    pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

    pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
    pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
    pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
    pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
    pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
    pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
    pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

    pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
    pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
    pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Pods for XXX
  pod 'react-native-signature-capture', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-signature-capture/react-native-signature-capture.podspec'
  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'
  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
  pod 'react-native-onesignal', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'
  pod 'RNI18n', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-i18n'
  pod 'SentryReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sentry'
  pod 'react-native-version-number', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-version-number'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'
  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
  pod 'react-native-background-upload', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-background-upload'
  pod 'react-native-document-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-document-picker'
  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question :

In our case this error was due to us having multiple configurations (staging, production, development) in our Xcode project.

Adding `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/../$CONFIGURATION-$PLATFORM_NAME` to Library Search Path of our Target in Build Settings solved the issue!

Answer (score -2):

[image: print]

Do you insert this line within that field?